# Implementing Numpy into nth factorial of n

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I've tried a few methods of implementing numpy into my program below, but every way I've attempted it drastically decreases performance. Is there expected with my use case, or is there a way to implement it with a performance increase instead of decrease?

```
import multiprocessing
import argparse
from datetime import datetime
from math import log10

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    formatter_class=argparse.HelpFormatter,
    description="Calcs n factorial",
    usage=""
)

parser.add_argument("-n", "--number", type=int, default=2)

args = parser.parse_args()

def getlog(send_end, i, threads, num, n, inc):
    begin = datetime.now()
    start = num-inc*i
    end = num-inc*(i+1) if i < threads-1 else 0
    output = sum(map(log10, range(start, end, -n)))
    send_end.send(output)
    final = datetime.now()
    duration = final-begin
    print("{},{},{},{}".format(i, duration, start, end))

def main():
    n = args.number
    num = int('1'*n)
    threads = multiprocessing.cpu_count() if num/multiprocessing.cpu_count() > multiprocessing.cpu_count() else 1
    inc = int(num/threads)
    inc -= inc%n
    jobs = []
    pipe_list = []
    for i in range(threads):
        recv_end, send_end = multiprocessing.Pipe(False)
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=getlog, args=(send_end, i, threads, num, n, inc))
        jobs.append(p)
        pipe_list.append(recv_end)
        p.start()
    for proc in jobs:
        proc.join()
    e = sum([output.recv() for output in pipe_list])

    print('%.2fe%d' % (10**(e % 1), e // 1))
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = datetime.now()
    main()
    end = datetime.now()
    print(end-start)
```

Comment: This should be pretty straightforward just by replacing regular Python operations with NumPy operations. You probably just didn't realize you should remove the `map` and apply `numpy.log10` to the array directly.

Comment: (NumPy will use a lot more memory, though. The design of NumPy involves a ton of fully-materialized giant scratch arrays, while your current code is iterator-based.)

Comment: Numba or Cython would let you avoid the giant scratch arrays.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica The giant arrays could be done in chunks, large enough to profit from NumPy but not so large that they're a problem.

Comment: This is what I've got, that I've done before. It significantly decreases performance. I've tried getting a numpy array to work, but I can't get it to work no matter how hard I try (I've spent days trying to get them to work in the past) https://pastebin.com/zKyQYG07

Comment: Just taking the code in the question and replacing the `output` computation with `np.sum(np.log10(np.arange(start, end, -n))` should do it. (You could apply the chunking memory optimization suggested by superb rain by adding up the results for smaller ranges.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I do plan on applying that, because as I'm sure you two are aware, this very quickly eats up gigabytes. I just want to get performance improved before I spend a whole lot of time optimizing the memory usage

Comment: arr = np.array([range(start, 0, -(n*threads))]), output = np.sum(np.log10(arr)). These work great, with one exception. The log10 itself once the array is generated is almost instant. However the array generation itself takes 3 times longer than without implementing numpy. I suspect due to the limitations between C Long and range() that we discussed about on my other post.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica using arrange instead of range did the trick. Thank you! FYI: an order of magnitude faster than without using numpy. Goes from 35 seconds at n=11 to 3.5 seconds. This OoM benefit holds true for all that I've tested.